# Breaking the while loop using keyboard

Tags: c++, windows, while-loop, break

In my application I am displaying images using an infinite while loop. I want to break the while loop whenever a predefined key is pressed. I have tried using GetAsyncKeyState()

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
        {       
            break;
            printf("Exiting Loop\n");
        }
```

But this is not working!!

The second approach I have used is to get the ascii value of the key using getch() method. So something like this,

```
# include conio.h  // Required header file
int keyVal;
keyVal = getch();
if (keyVal == 27)
 {
   break;
 }
```

However, this approach is making my application non-responsive.

Any ideas about how to break the while loop using keyboard events or mouse events? It could be any key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is it not working? If you expect something to print, than place the print statement **before** you `break` and leave the loop.

Comment: "this is not working" needs a clarification. What do you do? What happens? What do you expect to happen? Please describe in terms of user experience (what the user does; what the user sees; what the user should see); add screenshots if you think they are relevant.

Comment: BTW it might be easier to describe your problem while using a debugger (I hope you have and use it).

Comment: @StoryTeller: Why would you change the language in the tags? The OP is asking about C++. Even asking for alternative approaches, which might differ between C and C++.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, the code posted (and the conio.h header) is a strong implication that the OP has mistagged this as c++, since they do not fully understand the difference between the languages.

Comment: Hey StoryTeller,
Thanks for your reply. I tried it again and it's working but it's not so stable. Sometimes I have to hit ESC three times to change to break the loop.

Comment: Well, that's the thing. `GetAsyncKeyState` only tells you the state of the key *at the moment it is called*, it doesn't tell you if it was hit beforehand.

Comment: You should handle the `WM_KEYDOWN` [message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280.aspx) in your message processing loop, have a flag indicating if [Enter] (`VK_RETURN`) was pressed and check that flag in your loop as a breaking condition.

Answer (score 2):

As you have `conio.h` you can test for a keypress in a non-blocking way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int k = 0;

    while (k != 27) {

        // do your stuff
        // ...

        // test for keypress
        if(_kbhit()) {
            k = _getch();
        }
    }

    printf("Escaped\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply. I tried this but it's not checking for keypress. In other words the program is never meeting the if condition of _kbhit(). Do you know any reasons why kbhit() function doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps if you are using the Windows API. I wrote it this way because of what you tried in the question - you found `getch` blocks. If you are using the API then test for the keyboard messages as suggested above